# how to copy a file(input from user) with the name edited to the same directory?

Tags: perl

I would like to request a txt file from user and duplicated an exact copy with the name edited on the duplicated file in the same location.

Eg: User provide /file/works/done/abc.txt

The duplicated file will need to be /file/works/done/abc_**edited**.txt

I am able to duplicate the file.However, I cant append the name to the one I wish to have.
Assumption: `$file` is argument from user, eg: `$file` is /file/works/done/abc.txt 
Code as below:

```
my $a = '_edited'; 
my $duplicatedfile = $file.$a; 
copy($file,$duplicatedfile) or die "Failed to copy $file: $!\n
```

After execution, the duplicated file is /file/works/done/abc.txt_edited 
However the one that I wish to have is /file/works/done/abc_edited.txt

Answer (score 1):

Show us some code and a problem you're having with it, but please don't ask us to write the whole thing for you. You might want to look at the `File::Copy` module for an easy-to-use "copy file" method.

Oh well, after reading your comment it looks like all you need is something like

```
my $new_file_name = $file;
$new_file_name =~ s/\.([^\.]+)$/_edited.$1/;
```

Comment: I did not expect full code frm others.I am able to duplicate the file.However, i cant append the name to the one i wish to have. assumption : $file is argument from user,eg: $file is /file/works/done/abc.txt 

Code as below :
 my $a = '_edited'; 
my $duplicatedfile = $file.$a; 
copy($file,$duplicatedfile) or die "Failed to copy $file: $!\n 




After execution, the duplicated file is /file/works/done/abc.txt_edited However the one that i wish to have is /file/works/done/abc_edited.txt

Comment: @Steven: Please edit your original question to add the code and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
use File::Basename;

my $full_path = '/file/works/done/abc.txt';
my ($name, $path, $ext) = fileparse($full_path, qr/\.[^.]*/);
my $new_full_path = $path.$name.'_edited'.$ext;

print $new_full_path;
```